# fix Helm-operation pod failing for helm-cmd command container with exit code 123 in terminated state in rancher

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, rancher, helm3, rancher-rke

POD Helm-operation status shows error with multiple pod creation. This is a multi-container deployment but fails for **helm** container in terminated state but **proxy** container is in Ready state

```
cattle-fleet-system         gitjob-69f7bc54b4-ktpqg                    1/1     Running     0          20h
cattle-system               helm-operation-59ldb                       1/2     Error       0          106s
cattle-system               helm-operation-dqt64                       1/2     Error       0          2m2s
cattle-system               helm-operation-dt9bh                       1/2     Error       0          7m1s
cattle-system               helm-operation-lxxrm                       1/2     Error       0          7m10s
cattle-system               helm-operation-mp4m4                       1/2     Error       0          2m10s
cattle-system               helm-operation-vbqlk                       1/2     Error       0          114s
```

```yaml
Containers:
  helm:
    Container ID:  
    Image:         ***/rancher/shell:v0.1.14
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://*******/rancher/shell@sha256:6d3cd636eddc5342888888888888888764dfe86af868b20f6967f12
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      helm-cmd
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    123
      Started:      Fri, 18 Mar 2022 12:28:37 +0100
      Finished:     Fri, 18 Mar 2022 12:28:39 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      KUBECONFIG:  /home/shell/.kube/config
    Mounts:
      /home/shell/.kube/config from user-kubeconfig (ro,path="config")
      /home/shell/helm from data (ro)
  proxy:
    Container ID:  docker://f77ed026fdf9d88c106a45628a58888888888f2b2fcfd9a53
    Image:         **************/rancher/shell:v0.1.14
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://*********.azurecr.io/rancher/shell@sha256:6d38888888888ddc5342bcf67461d888888888889764dfe86af868b20f6967f12
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      sh
      -c
      kubectl proxy --disable-filter || true
```

Comment: kubectl logs helm-operation-2kspm -c helm -n cattle-system >>>>>>>> 

helm upgrade --force-adopt=true --history-max=5 --install=true --namespace=cattle-fleet-system --reset-values=true --timeout=5m0s --values=/home/shell/helm/values-fleet-100.0.2-up0.3.8.yaml --version=100.0.2+up0.3.8 --wait=true fleet /home/shell/helm/fleet-100.0.2-up0.3.8.tgz
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: "fleet" has no deployed releases